# How to simply count the documents by a given criteria (mongo aggregation framework)?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to simply count the documents. What would be the correct way to do the following:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate({
    $match: { // go by the indexed field
        date: {
            $gte: new Date(2013,1,20),
            $lte: new Date(2013,1,27)
        }
    }
},{
    $match: { // go by some other field
        someField: 'someValue'
    }
},{
    $count: { // $sum? $group? $anythingElse?
        // ???????
    }
})
```

Comment: If you just want to count by date:

db.my_collection.count({date:{$gte: new Date(2013,1,20)}, date:{$lte: new Date(2013,1,27)}})

Comment: @orid: the performance is NOT the same if the index is on dates only. Hence, first I am filtering by dates and only after by other criteria.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `$group` with `$sum`. Something like this:

```
$group: {
  _id: null,
  count: {$sum: 1}
}
```

[SQL to Aggregation Framework mapping chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/).

Comment: If `_id` carries some value like `docsWithSomeValueCount` is it even better from coding style/readability perspective?

Comment: @BreakPhreak: yeah, sure, you can assign it any constant value.